# Zend Framework transactions (Zend_db_adapter)

Tags: php, zend-framework, transactions

I have a problem with transactions

```
$backendB = new BackendBanner();//BackendBanner and ImageBanner extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
$backendB->getAdapter()->beginTransaction(); // starting transaction

try {
      $backendB->getAdapter()->insert('module_adv_banner',$data);
      $lastID = $backendB->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();
      $imageBanner = new ImageBanner();
      $imageBanner->getAdapter()->insert('module_adv_filebanner',$imgdata);
      $imageBanner->getAdapter()->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
      $backendB->getAdapter()->rollBack();
      echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

When this controller action executed, I have an SQL error in second insert operator:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id_banner1' in 'field list'
```

But rollback is not working, first insert query executed successfully and row inserted to the table.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: What database you use? If it is mysql - what storage engine is used for your tables?

Comment: Tables engine was MyISAM, that does not work with transactions. Changed to InnoDB and everything is ok.

Comment: Have you check if `id_banner1` is really present or defined in your model while entering?

Comment: this SQL error is sample, that I did to check, is transaction works or not. Problem already solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you use MyISAM that doesn't support transactions